# Obtain lock on P4 through Java Code

Tags: java, perforce

I want to obtain lock on P4 Branch through Java Code. Any one know hoe to achieve it through Java?

I use the below code:

```
IBranchSpec ibranchSpec = underlyingPerforceOptionsServer .getBranchSpec("//Tools/Patch/bin/");
ibranchSpec.setLocked(true);
```

Problem here is `ibranchSpec` contains all depot, I'm not sure why.

API for setLock Says, it will start working only after server update is done. I tried using something like that:

```
ibranchSpec.Update();
```

and it throws below exception. Any ideas?

```
com.perforce.p4java.exception.RequestException: Error in branch specification.
  You cannot use the default branch view; it is just a sample.
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're describing is because you're working with a new branch spec, not an existing one.

But you're probably encountering a common confusion, which is to confuse a branch **spec** with a set of **files** in the repository.

That is, the branch **spec** which describes how //Tools/Release/bin/... is mapped to //Tools/Patch/bin/... is different from the set of **files** in //Tools/Patch/bin/...

In general, Perforce workflows don't typically lock sets of files, since the whole point of Perforce is to enable concurrent editing of work by many users, with merging of changes to manage conflict resolution.

However, if you have a higher-level development workflow in which you want to control who and when can check into certain sections of the repository at certain times, that is absolutely reasonable.

In my experience, the best way to do this is to use the Perforce **protections** mechanism: establish a protections file describing the various sections of your repository, and who can submit to which section. Use user groups to describe sets of users, and try to keep your overall protections table reasonably simple.

Then, to "lock" or "unlock" a section of your repository (a "branch") from a group of users, you update your protections table to deny ("lock") or grant ("unlock") permission to that group to write to that branch.

This related question has a great description of the technique in its answers: [Locking a branch in perforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678257/locking-a-branch-in-perforce)